# Vector Subspace 0 vs Unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey just a quick question why does a vector by 2x2(real entries) when v = (1,0)eR^2 and u = {AeR^2x2 | Av=0} is a subspace

**while**

a vector that is 2x2 WITH complex entries , u = {AeR^2x2 | A is unitary} is not a subspace ?

What is the reason for real entries to have a subspace while a unitary doesnt have one. or do I have this backwards?

Answer (score 0):

These are totally different things, and this is not about any difference between complex and real numbers.

The equation $Av=0$ is *linear* in $A$ given that $v$ is fixed, so that its solution will be indeed a *linear* subspace (containing the null matrix, and closed under linear combinations).

On the other hand, the property *unitary* (or, for another example, *invertible*) is *not linear*, in exactly the sense that unitary [resp. invertible] matrices do not form a linear subspace among matrices, and this can be seen easiest by observing that the matrix $0$ is not unitary (neither invertible), while $0$ should be included in all linear subspaces.

Comment: So since in the first part v is fixed, and av=0 is linear, it produces contains a subspace. While Since the 2nd equation has complex values and doesnt nesscarily have a v, and unitary is not linear and since the matrix is not 0 its not a subspace. Am I understanding this correctly ?